# Undefined property after sorting array

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting, undefined, selection-sort

This is my function, on my console I got the sorted array, with a property on my array object which's key is undefined, and the property's value is the last item of the array. My question is how did that property was created, why, and what does a property called undefined mean.

```
const selectionSort = function (arr) {
  for (let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    let smallest = arr[i];
    let currentIndex;
    for (let j = i + 1; j < arr.length; j++) {
      if (arr[j] < smallest) {
        smallest = arr[j];
        currentIndex = j;
      }
      if (j === arr.length - 1) {
        arr[currentIndex] = arr[i];
        arr[i] = smallest;
      }
    }
  }
  return arr;
};
```

Comment: If `if (arr[j] < smallest)` never succeeds, you won't assign `currentIndex`. Then `arr[currentIndex]` will create an `undefined` key.

Comment: hello there, did you know that undefined is not a property name but it means your variable is having undefined value

Comment: BTW, if you're only doing something on the last iteration of the loop, you should just do it *after* the loop is done rather than test the loop iteration variable.

Comment: @NaldDev It will be a property name if you do `arr[currentIndex] = something` when `currentIndex` is undefined.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you assign value to `currentIndex` inside the first `if` condition, so in an unsorted array you use an unassigned variable as index.

```js
const selectionSort = function (arr) {
  for (let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    let smallest = arr[i];
    let currentIndex;
    for (let j = i + 1; j < arr.length; j++) {
      if (arr[j] < smallest) {
        smallest = arr[j];
        currentIndex = j;
      }
      if (j === arr.length - 1) {
        console.log("currentIndex:", currentIndex);

        arr[currentIndex] = arr[i];
        arr[i] = smallest;
      }
    }
  }
  return arr;
};

let res1 = selectionSort([5,8]);
console.log(res1);

let res2 = selectionSort([5,3]);
console.log(res2);
```

What you are trying to do is called bubble-sort, and here is the code for it:

```js
const selectionSort = function (arr) {
  for (let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    for (let j = i + 1; j < arr.length; j++) {
      if (arr[j] < arr[i]) {
        let tmp = arr[i];
        arr[i] = arr[j];
        arr[j] = tmp;
      }
    }
  }
  return arr;
};

let res1 = selectionSort([5,8,1,99,45]);
console.log(res1);

let res2 = selectionSort([5,6,7,8]);
console.log(res2);
```